# Redactor toolbar z-index

Tags: redactor, redactor.js

I am using the latest version of Redactor and have noticed that the z-index of the toolbar is set above many other components (Bootstrap modal, drop-down menus, etc). I browsed the docs and could not find any mention of changing the toolbar's z-index.

What is the best way to fix this problem? Is there a setting I missed that can be called upon initializing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From Art at Imperavi-

> Thank you so much for reporting this. At this time, the only
>   workaround is to manually adjust Redactor's z-index, please see line
>   58 in redactor.css.